# AN error occurs 'could not lock table' after running VBA in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access I have created a button to email a report as a pdf. It works fine the first time I use then if I try and using it again it gives the error 'could not lock table'. I used the following code:

```
Private Sub Btn_TNA_Report_Click()
Dim MyDate As Date
Dim x2 As String
MyDate = Date    
x2 = Me.Email_Of_Contact_Person
DoCmd.SendObject acSendReport, "Rpt_TNA_Email", acFormatPDF, x2, , , "NMUH Request for Staff Education Places " & Date, "Dear Colleague," & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please find PDF of request attached." & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Thank you", True
End Sub
```

I have to close the database and reopen it every time to unlock the table. I tried to add a line before opening report to delete the offending table but that didnt work either.

Any thoughts, guys?

Comment: That code _as is_ will not lock anything. What could lock something is the report. So, check that out. As a start, replace it with a simple report that runs zero code.

Comment: Thanks Gustav, you gave me an idea! I didn't think the code was causing it either. I had the report open when sending to pdf etc. I simply added  DoCmd.Close before the docmd.SendObject line and it solved it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to approach this problem.

First check DB master tables to know which process/user is locking the table. 
Identify the location which is causing this lock and try to perform commit to release all locks on that table.

Second, you need not close DB. you could check and release locks on the table, if you have adequate permissions. try to go this route.

Comment: Thanks for responding, unfortunately I don't quite follow. How do you go about these things please?

Comment: Did you try to search on how locks could be removed on table? just search in google. you will find everything.